# Can I host in app engine for a domain purchased already

Tags: java, google-app-engine, hosting

I have a domain name purchased already, can I host a website in Google app engine for that.  If it is possible please tell me the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.  Set up an app in App Engine, then map the custom domain to it in the cloud console, and point its DNS to App Engine.

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply :)
I have added a TXT record in DNS config, when i am trying to verify from Google it is saying as below,

 Verification failed for stockboo.com using the DNS TXT record method (2 minutes ago). We couldn't find the verification token in your domain's TXT records. You might need to wait a few minutes before Google sees your changes to the TXT records.
Show found DNS TXT records 
v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  You set up the TXT for `websitewelcome.com`, but checked it for `stockboo.com`?  An MX record is different than a TXT record.

Comment: Hi, Thanks... I got it ..already a TXT is there by that name,it is fetching that value.

Comment: But now i have deleted all the TXT records, but still  the same error :(

Comment: Did you add back the TXT record that Google is looking for to validate?

Comment: Yes i have added now, i can see in DNS configuration.

Comment: Now try to revalidate in the cloud console

Comment: :( same error as mentioned above, my DNS provider is resellerclub. Please suggest me, i am struck

Comment: I have nothing further to add.  Domain verification by TXT record is a rather simple and straightforward method, that I have never seen fail.  You add the text record with the hashed string that Google provides.  They check for that record, and if it is there, they verify.  Simple.  Please double check everything.  There must be a simple mistake, like a typo, or wrong domain.

Comment: Now purchased a new domain in google, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Definitely. Here is the step by step documentation on [using and setting up custom domain in Google app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl).

[Here is another step by step video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqjFOIjRYBI)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the additional info :),
But facing issue in mentioned in "GAEfan" comments